# Why doesn't ethereum enforce a transaction ordering to prevent MEV?

Tags: protocol, mev

Why not just enforce ordering by priority fee? Just say a block is invalid if the transactions are out-of-order with respect to their priority fees. That way smart contracts can limit priority fees to stop sandwich attacks. Is this not possible for any technical reasons?

Answer (score 0):

There was already a system called Flashbots that attempted to make MEV distribution opportunities more fairly available, and a system of random transaction ordering was proposed by researchers, but ultimately, because blockchain is unregulated, there is no system to enforce a specific order of transactions is necessary for this kind of arbitrage. And if this were to happen in traditional finance, it's illegal. To tackle this problem, some researchers believe that regulation is necessary to make Ethereum more compatible with traditional finance.

See: https://www.theregister.com/2022/03/31/ethereum_mining_mev/